# magento 2.2.3 Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18274-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: magento

On a Magento 2.2.3 instance after migrating data from Magento 1 via migration tool we're getting the following error in exceptions.log. The shop works fine, however this errors are still around and I can't really pinpoint it down. Any ideas for an approach?

[2018-10-01 09:00:08] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18274-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_temp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp` {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18274-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_temp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp` at /.../public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/Action/Row.php:32, Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DuplicateException(code: 1062): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18274-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_temp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp` at /.../public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:555, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18274-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_temp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_temp` at /.../public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18274-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY' at /.../public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []